# setOnEditorActionListener not working for edit texts next to each other end of layout

Tags: android

here' the code
I  have two edit Text in a row in my lay out,and when I touch next on keyboard it does not change the focus.
the setOnEditorActionListener does not work till i add extra editText

```
               <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/firstText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/secondText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                     />
```

code:

```
  firstText.setOnNextActionListener(new CallBack<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void call(KeyEvent data) {
                secondText.requestEditTextFocus();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, please mention it.

Comment: You can achieve this via inputType = actionNext as well. No need to use listener.

Comment: it does not work either.

Comment: it does not work either.i have 2 edit Text next to each other and I want the focus change after I touch next key on the keyboard.

Comment: do  you want to achieve focus eachother in editext ? means when you press next in firsttext keyboard you should go secondText and when youpress next in secondText keyboard you want to go firstText like that?

Comment: or you want  just press next in firsttext and you go secondText with focus? @mojgantajfar please confirm

Comment: I want press next in firsttext and  go secondText with focus

Answer (score 1):

Give one value into edittext in xml file ..

```
  android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Show below three ways, you can got you want Using any one of them

- `inputType ="actionNext"` attribute

  or
- `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

  or
- `android:singleLine="true"` and
  `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/secondText"`

  on your **.xml** you can do this.

If you want to do it **programmatically** in your activity or fragment then try below:-

```
firstText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {

            secondText.requestEditTextFocus();

            return true; // Focus will do whatever you put in the logic.
        }
        return false;  // Focus will change according to the actionId
    }
});
```

**I have tested with set Programmtically with changes  `secondText.requestEditTextFocus();` to `secondText.requestFocus();`  and its working fine.**

Please show below Screenshotes

[image]

[image]

Comment: String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'actionNext').

Comment: Use android:singleLine="true" attribute and try

Comment: you can also add at programmtically as i defined above

Comment: what options you checked?

Comment: I checked all the solutions above.

Comment: you have checked programmtically also right? can you check tell me what is requestEditTextFocus() in your code?

Comment: try {
            textField.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            textField.requestFocus();
            final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(textField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

Comment: firstText.setOnNextActionListener(new CallBack<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void call(KeyEvent data) {
           
                secondText.getEditText().requestFocus();
            }
        }); it didn't work for me but thanks anyway.

Comment: @mojgantajfar why you take edittext.setOnNextActionListener() method please use editext.setOnEditorActionListener() as i used in my answer and It working same. please replace your code with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/secondText"  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/secondText"    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/secondText"    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/secondText"
```

Comment: it does not work till i add third edit Text below them